# Is the co-limit of a chain of normal subspaces necessarily normal?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Suppose $ X_0 \subset X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \dots$ is a chain of normal subspaces of $X$ such that $X= \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$. Assume that $X$ has the colimit topology w.r.t. these subspaces. Can we conclude that $X$ is normal ?  Does it help if we assume that $X_i \to X_{i+1} $ are closed embeddings ?

The motivation for the question is as follows. CW-complexes arise as co-limits of normal spaces which are obtained by gluing boundary of disks to lower dimensional cells. Essentially if $X$ is a CW complex, then the inclusions in the chain above are closed embeddings and are obtained by attaching n-cells. If we use this additional information, it can be shown (as in Hatcher's appendix) that CW complexes are normal. However I was wondering if this is true in a more general setting.

Also please provide some references where I may learn about co-limit topologies and the properties preserved under them.  Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

The answer is positive, the space $X$ is normal, provided we assume that $X_i \to X_{i+1} $ are closed embeddings.
Indeed, let $A$, $B$ be two disjoint subsets of the space $X$. Using the normality of all spaces $X_i$, by induction we can build sequences $\{U_i\}$ and $\{V_i\}$ such that for each $i$ the following conditions hold

1) Both $U_i$ and $V_i$ are open subsets of the space $X_i$.

2) $A\cap X_i\subset U_i$ and $B\cap X_i\subset V_i$.

3) The sets $U_i$ and $V_i$ have disjoint closures $\overline{U_i}^{X_i}$ and $\overline{V_i}^{X_i}$ in the space $X_i$.

4) $\overline{U_i}^{X_i}\subset U_{i+1}$ and $\overline{V_i}^{X_i}\subset V_{i+1}$.

Put $U=\bigcup U_i$ and $V=\bigcup V_i$. The construction implies that $A\subset U$, $B\subset V$, and 
both $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open subsets of the space $X$.